# How to find first TextFormField that is in error after calling formKey.currentState?.validate() in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a list of `TextFormField()` widgets within a `Form()` widget that is in a `CustomScrollView()`. When I call the form's `validate()` method all the fields are correctly validated. However, because there are a lot of fields, the first (and possibly only) field actually in error may be out of view. So the form doesn't submit, however the user needs to manually scroll in search of the error.

How can I get the `scrollView` to scroll to the first field in error?

I know that I can set a `FocusNode` for the form field and then issue `requestFocus()` and the `scrollView` will scroll to that field - which is what I want, **HOWEVER**, I am unable to figure out which field is actually in error?

Does anyone know what is the best way to achieve my goal of scrolling to the first `TestFormField` in error for a `Form` in a `scrollView`?

Comment: i think this article help you https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/04/hint-4-ensure-a-textfield-or-textformfield-is-visible-in-the-viewport-when-has-the-focus/

Answer (score 1):

I have created an example that could be possible solution for you, adjust it to your needs:

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  final _controllerUsername = TextEditingController();
  final _controllerPassword = TextEditingController();
  final _controllerEmail = TextEditingController();
  final _controllerAddress = TextEditingController();
  final _focusAddress = FocusNode();
  final _focusUsername = FocusNode();
  final _focusPassword = FocusNode();
  final _focusEmail = FocusNode();
  int? errorIndex;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late List<FocusNode> focusNodes = [
    _focusUsername,
    _focusPassword,
    _focusEmail,
    _focusAddress,
  ];

  void validateForm() {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      errorIndex = null;
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
      );
    } else {
      print("error occured at $errorIndex form field");
      focusNodes[errorIndex!].requestFocus();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'username'),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                controller: _controllerUsername,
                focusNode: _focusUsername,
                validator: (value) {
                  var validation = value?.isNotEmpty ?? true;
                  errorIndex = validation ? null : 0;
                  return validation ? null : "Input your username";
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'password'),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                controller: _controllerPassword,
                focusNode: _focusPassword,
                validator: (value) {
                  var validation = value?.isNotEmpty ?? true;
                  errorIndex = validation ? errorIndex : errorIndex ?? 1;
                  return validation ? null : "Input your password";
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'email'),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                controller: _controllerEmail,
                focusNode: _focusEmail,
                validator: (value) {
                  var validation = value?.isNotEmpty ?? true;
                  errorIndex = validation ? errorIndex : errorIndex ?? 2;
                  return validation ? null : "Input your email";
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'address'),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                controller: _controllerAddress,
                focusNode: _focusAddress,
                validator: (value) {
                  var validation = value?.isNotEmpty ?? true;
                  errorIndex = validation ? errorIndex : errorIndex ?? 3;
                  return validation ? null : "Input your address";
                },
              ),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: validateForm, child: Text('submit'))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```